# Solr searchField schema for a single match

Tags: solr, xsd, search-engine

I would like to write a specific fieldType that will work as shown at the example below:
Say we have a name: `foo MooBar (f00B2r)`;

- "f" => `foo MooBar (f00B2r)` (and others with a "f")
- "foo moob" => `foo MooBar (f00B2r)` (and others with a "foo moob", etc.)
- "foo (f0" => `foo MooBar (f00B2r)`
- "moobar f" => `foo MooBar (f00B2r)`
- "(f00b2r)" => `foo MooBar (f00B2r)`
- "bar" => none
- "moobar o" => none
- "moob foo" => none

My problems:

1. If i search for "moobar f" i'll get none;
2. If i search for "(f00b2r)" i'll get none;

my fieldType in solr/conf/schema.xml:

```
<fieldType name="frontMatch" class="solr.TextField" positionIncrementGap="255">
  <analyzer type="index">
    <tokenizer class="solr.LowerCaseTokenizerFactory"/>
    <filter class="solr.LowerCaseFilterFactory"/>
    <filter class="solr.EdgeNGramFilterFactory" minGramSize="1" maxGramSize="255" side="front" />
  </analyzer>
  <analyzer type="query">
    <tokenizer class="solr.WhitespaceTokenizerFactory"/>
    <filter class="solr.LowerCaseFilterFactory"/>
    <filter class="solr.EdgeNGramFilterFactory" minGramSize="1" maxGramSize="255" side="front" />
  </analyzer>
</fieldType>
```

*P.S.*
Sorry for my English and Thanks;

Comment: I don't know about the first issue but as far as the second is concerned -- have you tried escaping the parentheses? E.g., querying for `\(foob2r\)` instead of `(foob2r)`?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The solution for me:
Part of `scheme.xml`

```
<fieldType name="frontMatch" class="solr.TextField" positionIncrementGap="0" >
  <analyzer type="index">
    <tokenizer class="solr.WhitespaceTokenizerFactory"/>
    <filter class="solr.LowerCaseFilterFactory"/>
    <filter class="solr.EdgeNGramFilterFactory" minGramSize="1" maxGramSize="255" side="front" />
  </analyzer>
  <analyzer type="query">
    <tokenizer class="solr.WhitespaceTokenizerFactory"/>
    <filter class="solr.LowerCaseFilterFactory"/>
    <filter class="solr.EdgeNGramFilterFactory" minGramSize="1" maxGramSize="255" side="front" />
  </analyzer>
</fieldType>
```

That solves the **second** problem.
To solve the **first** one:
Every query should be done with [Proximity](http://wiki.apache.org/solr/SolrRelevancyCookbook?highlight=%28%5C~1000000%29);
Number 1000000 is equal to operator "AND" when searching.
So, the *search query* looks like: `name:"moobar f"~1000000`;
 where `name` is the field we're searching in;